# Launch Blender cycles render from terminal with tiles rendering view

Tags: python, rendering, uv-image-editor, command-line

Sorry for the title, I don't know how to better explain my "problem".

In a nutshell: I would like to open from terminal or win prompt a blender file and see it render on the screen the same way it does when you hit f12, I mean seeing the tiles rendering on screen. The result has to be a windowed UV/Image editor with no bars and menus (did it before as you can see i the code below I called it 'viewport') that let you see the progress of rendering.

Here's my terminal command:

`blender /path/to/file.blend -S scene_name -W -p 200 200 800 600 -P /path/to/script.py`

Here my script.py content:

```
import bpy
```

`bpy.context.window.screen = bpy.data.screens['viewport']
bpy.ops.render.render(animation=False, write_still=True, use_viewport=True, scene="scene_name")`

the -S argument is redundant I think, but this isn't a problem.

I need your help, you pros! :-)

Comment: as a result of the script I made I get a hourglass and the screen locked until the rendering is finished. After that It opens the Blender Window I want in the 'viewport' screen but with no render result at all.

Comment: not able to test it at the moment but did find `bpy.ops.render.view_show()`
`Toggle show render view`

Comment: Thanks Rob!Ok, now I know it's a context problem, to solve by using override and I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I manage to solve my problem adding some line to my python script. This is the result:

```
import bpy
bpy.data.screens['viewport'].scene = bpy.data.scenes['scene']
bpy.context.window.screen = bpy.data.screens['viewport']
bpy.context.screen.scene = bpy.data.scenes['scene']
bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT', animation=False, write_still=True, use_viewport=False, scene="scene")
```

This makes me see the tiles rendering the correct scene and at the end it save the image in the dir specified in the render settings tab.

Now I've come across other issue but this is another story.

Thank you guys!